# Boltzmann distribution: derivation from canonical distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm trying to understand the Maxwell-Boltzman Distribution, and in particular the derivation from the boltzman distribution for energy. I have successfully created an incorrect derivation, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it :). Any guidance would be much appreciated!

I believe that the probability density function for the energy, $E$, of a random particle in a system at equilibrium is meant to look like this:

$$f_E(x) = Ae^{-\frac{x}{kT}}$$

To simplify things I'll just consider the particular case:

$$f_E(x) = e^{-x}$$

The cumulative distribution function is then:

$$Pr(E\leq x) = F_E(x) = 1-e^{-x}$$
Now suppose all the particles in our system are of mass $1$, so, ignoring potential energy, the random variable governing the speed of a given particle is $V = \sqrt{2E}$. Now we want to find the distribution of the speeds. We can do this as so:

$$F_V(v)=Pr(V\leq v) = Pr(\sqrt{2E}\leq v) = Pr\left(E\leq \frac{v^2}{2}\right) = F_E\left(\frac{v^2}{2}\right)$$

and so

$$F_V(v)=1-e^{-\frac{v^2}{2}}$$

and finally

$$f_V(v)= ve^{-\frac{v^2}{2}}$$.

This is *almost* right, however, the Maxwell-Boltzman distribution would predict a pdf with $v^2$ rather than $v$, something like:

$$f_V(v)= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}v^2e^{-\frac{v^2}{2}}.$$

Can anyone point out the mistake in my logic? Thanks!

Comment: The measure is wrong. Semi-classically it is $\frac{d^3p d^3x}{h^3}$. $e^{-E/k_BT}=e^{-p^2/(2mk_BT)}$ gives the probability density of finding the particle in a cell (of volume $\frac{d^3p d^3x}{h^3}$)  in phase space up to some normalization factor.